# Sharing Violation exception when trying to open a file

Tags: delphi

When my Delphi app tries to open a text file with `TFileStream.Create` in `fmOpenRead + fmShareCompat` mode, I get a Sharing Violation exception. The same file can, in that moment, be opened with `notepad.exe`

I am writing to this file from multiple applications with the `fmOpenReadWrite + fmShareDenyNone` modes.

Any explanations?

Comment: Why are you using fmShareCompat? What is the thought process there? Also, do you not care about races? Also, don't use arithmetic to combine flags. Using logical or.

Comment: Indeed, it is very important to note that you MUST write `fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyNone`.

Comment: See also [TFileStream.Create - Open read write but allow others to readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70307149/4299358).

Answer (score 2):

`fmShareCompat` has a value of `$0000` on Windows, so it is basically meaningless when mixed with other flags (ie, `X + 0 = X` and `X or 0 = X`).

However, `FileOpen()` and `FileCreate()` (which `TFileStream.Create` calls internally) both treat `fmShareCompat` the exact same as `fmShareExclusive`.  Hence the exception if *anyone* already has the file open for *any* reason.

So, when you open/create the file, if you want other apps to be able to access the file while you have it open, you need to specify a more appropriate `fmShareDeny...` mode instead (unless you really want exclusive access, in which case use `fmShareExclusive` instead of `fmShareCompat`).

Comment: but if I use a fmShareDenyWrite I will not be able to write to the file from mutiple appplications, right?

Comment: While you have the file open with this `TFileStream`, yes. If you want to allow other apps to write to the file while this `TFileStream` is open, then you would have to use `fmShareDenyNone` instead. The point is, don't use `fmShareCompat`, that is the source of your sharing violation error, since it is treated the same as `fmShareExclusive`.